# Custom Object is not available to create report

Tags: reporting, custom-object

I have a custom object medical Inquiry and Allow report is checked on it. While trying to create report using System Admin the object is not coming up in the object list[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ensure the custom object has [Reporting enabled](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008srbIAA).

> Setup > App Setup > Create > Objects > Your Object > Edit > Check "Allow Reports" checkbox

Once that is done you need to make sure a [custom report](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_defining_report_types.htm) type is setup for the object (or combination of objects) you wish to see.

> Setup > App Setup > Create > Report Type > Select New Custom Report Type

Comment: Allow Reports is checked for the custom object, but i'm not able to create custom report type for that object. In the Primary object drop down the custom object is not available. Please suggest.

Comment: there was a translation issue...solved now..thanks !!